# jQuery get and pipe don't work in IE 9 and 8

Tags: jquery

I have a html page with this script:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function GetWorkDone {
            alert(1);
            $.get( "http://Mylab:2323/Scripts/SC_FrameWork/SC_Live_2.1.js").pipe($.get("http://Mylab:2323/Scripts/SC_FrameWork/Sc_Widget.js", {}, function () {
                alert(2);

            }));
        }

        GetWorkDone();
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The second alert does not fire in IE9 & 8.
Works well with IE 10.

Is there a solution for this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$.getScript()` to load an external js file, also `pipe()` has been deprecated since version 1.8, you can use `$.when()` instead:

```
$.when( $.getScript( "http://Mylab:2323/Scripts/SC_FrameWork/SC_Live_2.1.js" ), $.getScript( "http://Mylab:2323/Scripts/SC_FrameWork/Sc_Widget.js" ) )
  .done(function( r1, r2 ) {
      alert(2)
});
```

The above code will call the alert after both scripts are successfully loaded.
For a more in depth explanation for the use of `$.when()` and the arguments in the "done" callback please refer to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)